# Css selecting canvas nested element

Tags: html, css

I[image]

Id like to select canvas element for styling purposes but I can get it done, is it due to fact that this is generated in flight and css wont see it after its generated?

I tried 'copy selection'

```
#drawing > div > div > canvas
```

but its also not working, the only way im able to add style is with use of developer tools..

```
#drawing  div  canvas {
  border: 10px solid #22cc37;
  padding: 100px;
}


div.ng2-pdf-viewer-container > div > canvas {
  padding: 100px;
  border: 10px solid #22cc37;

}

drawing > pdf-viewer > div > div > canvas {
  border: 10px solid #22cc37;
}

.drawing .ng2-pdf-viewer-container{
  border: 10px solid #22cc37;
}

drawing pdf-viewer div div canvas {
  border: 10px solid #22cc37;
}

.drawing .pdf-viewer div div canvas {
  border: 10px solid #22cc37;
}
```

this is my css file none of this seems to work..

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Images are nice but we prefer code

Comment: What are those exotic tags and how are they allowed (`<drawing>` and `<pdf-viewer>`) ?

Comment: those are angular components

Comment: @filemonczyk Oh.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this page out](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp), you are not using the selector correctly:

> The `element>element` selector is used to select elements with a specific parent.
>
> **Note: Elements that are not directly a child of the specified parent, are not selected.**

So, Try `drawing > pdf-viewer > div > div > canvas` instead.

**Edit 1:** Now that you added your CSS file, if you want to select an element whose tag-name is `drawing`, then you don't need to prefix that tag-name with either a `.` or a `#` (the former is for selecting elements with a specific class-name, the latter is used to select an element with a specific ID).

Also, try this out and see if it works:

```
drawing  div  canvas {
  border: 10px solid #22cc37 !important;
  padding: 100px !important;
}
```

The example above results in this when I try it out (even without the `!important`s, so if it doesn't work for you, the issue is not with your CSS, you are probably overriding the styles somewhere else in your code): 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `>`s should resolve it, because then you basically say that it must not be a direct child, but it may skip some children.